# Mobile Nav Javascript Not Working

Tags: javascript, css, responsive, nav

I'm a bit of a beginner here, and doing exercises on FreeCodeCamp. While working on the Portfolio Site project, I tried adding a Javascript responsive mobile nav to the site from some code at ws3schools.

The nav is showing up fine, but clicking it does nothing. Here's my CodePen, any ideas what I did that's preventing it from popping up the nav links on click? https://codepen.io/colum1225/pen/xLwMJG

Here's the nav bar code:

```
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <h3>Brandon Ray</h3>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<!-- CSS -->

.topnav {
  background-color: #2C8597;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
}

.topnav h3 {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 30px;
  letter-spacing: .04em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 27px 30px 27px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  transition: .5s;
}

.topnav a:active {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .topnav a {display: none;}
  .topnav .icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }
}

<!-- JS -->

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Great work so far.

You're missing a dot in-front of your `topnav` class selector for your `.responsive` rules. See the fixed CSS below,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

---

#### Fixing Overlap

To fix the overlap of your first mobile navigation dropdown menu item with your menu icon, try adding a `margin-top` to the first menu item. A good margin size would be the menu's height of (82px).

This rule would look as follows,

```
  .topnav.responsive a:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 82px;
  }
```

> Include this rule with your other **.topnav.responsive** rules (line ~77).

Comment: I *knew* it was something like that. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help. If you felt my answer directly solved the problem stated in your original post, please consider marking it as the Accepted Answer so others whom face the same issue may quickly refer to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your css you need a period before `topnav`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive a.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
    }
}
```

or you could remove the topnav part altogetther and just have the `responsive` part.

**Positioning fix:**

Change icons position back to relative and put the icon at the top of your nav:

HTML

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <h3>Brandon Ray</h3>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>  
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
```